# Cannot pass Title as parameter in Jquery message box

Tags: jquery

Here is my html markup

```
<div id="dialog" title="">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
    </form>
</div>
```

my call to messagebox

```
 $(function () {
         $("#A").on("click", function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             $('#dialog').data('opener', 'Test title').dialog('open');
         });
         });
```

and the messagebox itself

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    title: $(this).data('opener'),
    modal: false,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        'OK': function (e) {
            //Do something
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that the Title property of the MessageBox is always empty.
What am i doing wrong here?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

here is the JsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lqbxga8/2/)

Comment: @Popnoodles can you check the update please? Still no luck

Comment: the `title: $(this).data('opener')` is evaluated at the time you first initialize the modal. You cannot change it's value later and expect the value which was previously fetched and stored in the modal to be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `.data`.

Remove this line

```
title: $(this).data('opener'),
```

and open the dialog like such

```
$('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'My New title').dialog('open');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lqbxga8/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

**This is a timing issue**. When the dialog get's initialized, `#dialog` does not have a data attribute `data-opener`. And it does not have a value until `#A` is clicked. And adding `data-opener` at click time does not necessarily update `#dialog`'s title, so you might as well set the title of the dialog before opening it.

You have to set the title of the dialog like so:

```
$('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Test title').dialog('open');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/7Lqbxga8/3/)

Comment: May as well also remove this `title: $(this).data('opener'),`